# System.DirectoryServices.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the current user logged into the computer via .net MVC. I was able to get the Domain name, but now i want to get the First and Last name. 
The code that gave me the domain details was as follows:

```
string userName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

However, when I tried to get the First and Last name using the following:

```
using (PrincipalContext domainContext = new 
PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {    
       UserPrincipal up =UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, 
       System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
       string agtName = up.Name;
       TempData["loginName"] = agtName;
     }
```

Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

I also added the references:

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

System.DirectoryServices
```

View Class:

```
<p>@TempData["loginName"]</p>
```

**Kept on receiving this error:**

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The (&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(|(userPrincipalName=)(distinguishedName=)(name=))) search filter is invalid.
```

Any work around for this or a different way to achieve Full name?

Comment: Are you already checked what string contained inside `userName`? Sounds like you need to add `<deny users="?" />` in web.config's authorization section and disable anonymous access setting in IIS.

Comment: That gives me a 404 error.